# Можно ли преобразовать Unicode в символы,а потом записать эти символы в файл?

Tags: java, unicode

Т.е и беру Unicode символ 1F780,затем каким-то образом преобразовываю его в символ и записываю этот символ в файл.Долго искал в инете,ничего не нашел.

Comment: символ не входит в Basic Multilingual Plane, поэтому в строковый литерал в ява-коде его нужно записывать, как суррогатную пару [`"\uD83D\uDF80"`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f780/index.htm) или как code point (с типом `int`). Дальше оно в байты в нужной кодировке преобразуется [как обычно](https://ideone.com/SEg4mF).

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь библиотекой [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava(java.lang.String))

```
str = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str);
```